# OSX Today View Access Core Data For Viewing Only

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, today-extension

I have an app that stores lots of information in core data and displays it on a NSTableView, i want to have a smaller version of this for my today view extension.

I know how to share User Defaults using app groups, but could someone give me instructions on how to share the core data file with my extension. And also how to use it because as far as i know

```
let appDel = NSApplication.SharedApplication.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

and

```
 context = appDel.managedObjectContext
```

wont work because they are files in the main app and i need those two things to query and view my data. Thanks in advance.